# Como colocar um código PHP dentro de um HTML que está armazenado em uma variável PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

Sou iniciante em PHP. Meu intuito é criar uma variável que armazenará trechos de uma DIV em HTML. Entretanto, alguns trechos desse HTML contêm instruções PHP, e não sei como deixar essas instruções "legíveis", por assim dizer.

Meu código está logo abaixo. Vejam que tenho a variável `$variavel`. Meu problema está dentro do parágrafo *professor*.

Grato!

```html
<?php

  $variavel .= ' 
                    <a href="meusite.php?id='.$row["id"].'" target="_blank">
                        <div class="grid__item large--three-tenths medium--five-tenths">
                        <img src="imagens/imagem.jpg" alt="'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'" title="'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'">
                        <p class="h6">'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'</p>
                        <p class="professor">

/* COMO COLOCAR ESTE TRECHO? */

                        $iddocurso = $row["id"];
                        $professor = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mdl_course";
                        $resultProf = $conn->query($professor);
                        
                        if ($resultProf->num_rows == 1) {
                            while($row2 = $resultProf->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo 'Professor: '.utf8_encode($row2["firstname"]).' '.utf8_encode($row2["lastname"]);
                            } 
                        } else if ($resultProf->num_rows > 1) {
                            $array_professores = array();
                            while ($row2 = $resultProf->fetch_array()){
                                $array_professores[] = utf8_encode($row2['firstname']).' '.utf8_encode($row2['lastname']);
                            }
                            $professores = implode('; ', $array_professores);
                            echo 'Professores: '.$professores;
                        } else {
                            echo "Sem professor cadastrado";
                        }
/* ATÉ AQUI */
                        
                        </p>
                        <span>Acessar</span>
                        </div>
                        </a>
  ';
  ?>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No php e html você deve sempre se lembrar que o php é executado antes do html ser exibido.

Php é executado no lado servidor (hospedagem) e html executado no lado cliente (navegador).

Então separe seu código para executar primeiro em php e depois coloque na variavel o que você quer exibir no html.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

// Primeiro execute seu php e em vez de usar "echo" para exibir durante a execução,
// coloque as variaveis para exibir depois no local que você quer q o resultado apareça:
// veja que troquei o "echo" por "$variavelderesultado" no seu código abaixo e mudei ele de posição.

    $iddocurso = $row["id"];
    $professor = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mdl_course";
    $resultProf = $conn->query($professor);
    
    if ($resultProf->num_rows == 1) {
        while($row2 = $resultProf->fetch_assoc()) {
            $variavelderesultado =  'Professor: '.utf8_encode($row2["firstname"]).' '.utf8_encode($row2["lastname"]);
        } 
    } else if ($resultProf->num_rows > 1) {
        $array_professores = array();
        while ($row2 = $resultProf->fetch_array()){
            $array_professores[] = utf8_encode($row2['firstname']).' '.utf8_encode($row2['lastname']);
        }
        $professores = implode('; ', $array_professores);
        $variavelderesultado = 'Professores: '.$professores;
    } else {
        $variavelderesultado = "Sem professor cadastrado";
    }

// depois que você ja executou o que queria ai sim você coloca a variavel armazenada onde deseja que apareça:

$variavel .= ' 
<a href="meusite.php?id='.$row["id"].'" target="_blank">
    <div class="grid__item large--three-tenths medium--five-tenths">
    <img src="imagens/imagem.jpg" alt="'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'" title="'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'">
    <p class="h6">'.utf8_encode($row["fullname"]).'</p>
    <p class="professor">

    '.$variavelderesultado.'
    
    </p>
    <span>Acessar</span>
    </div>
    </a>
  ';
  
  // E depois de tudo finalizado que você utiliza o "echo" para exibir o resultado.
  
  echo $variavel;
  
  ?>
```

Comment: Excelente explicação, Bruno!! Além de ter funcionando perfeitamente, conseguiu compreender a lógica e os princípios que você utilizou! Muito obrigado, cara!

Comment: @winiercape fico feliz em ter ajudado ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Sempre que você for misturar html com php , siga  essa regrinha básica:**

Seguinte:
Se a varável php está fechada com aspas dupla `""`, então todo html de dentro terá de estar contido por aspas simples `''`, ou vice versa. Além disso, sempre que for incluir um código **php** entre o código **html**, deverá fechar a aspas da variável (dupla, no caso do exemplo abaixo) seguido de . $codigo . e reinicia as aspas do html " como no exemplo abaixo.

O php de dentro segue a mesma linha de raciocínio.

Exemplo:
*Meu código com html e php dentro de uma variável php:*

```
<?php 
$variavelx = "<div class='nomedaclasse'>" . $codigophp . "</div>" . $codigophp2 . "<br>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Amanda! Eu consegui compreender esse princípio, e até pensei nele, mas como envolvia outros códigos dentro do HTML, ele não havia funcionado. Mas valeu pelo retorno!